# How to specify the principal entity to which the foreign key refers using the Fluent API?

Tags: foreign-keys, entity-framework-core, ef-fluent-api

How to specify the principal entity to which the foreign key refers using the Fluent API?

I am learning the EF Core through the tutorials over [here](https://www.learnentityframeworkcore.com/configuration/fluent-api/hasforeignkey-method).

I come across the following example:

```
public class Author
{
    public int AuthorId { get; set; }
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    public string LastName { get; set; }
    public ICollection<Book> Books { get; set; }
}
public class Book
{
    public int BookId { get; set; }
    public string Title { get; set; }
    public int AuthorFK { get; set; }
    public Author Author { get; set; }
}
public class SampleContext : DbContext
{
    public DbSet<Author> Authors { get; set; }
    public DbSet<Book> Books { get; set; }
    protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        modelBuilder.Entity<Book>()
            .HasForeignKey(p => p.AuthorFK);
    }
}
```

And I can not understand how the EF Core knows that the `AuthorFK` refers to the `Author` entity. I.e. if for instance, I would like the `AuthorFK` to be a foreign key for an entity different from the `Author` entity, how could I do that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Surprisingly, the tutorial is wrong there. The correct method is:

```cs
modelBuilder.Entity<Book>()
    .HasOne(e => e.Author)
    .WithMany()
    .HasForeignKey(e => e.AuthorFK);
```

The method shown (`modelBuilder.Entity<Book>().HasForeignKey`) doesn't exist.

I think when you see this it'll all make sense.